# Gauss-Krüger system to Unity Coordinate Conversion

Tags: unity, c#, coordinates, spatial-partitioning

In my recent project, I am getting an object file via a request to REST API and found that the OBJs (object file) are in Gauss-Kruger System. I want to know that how exactly I place the model as I have several objects so coordinate conversion should work between UCS(unity coordinate system) and Gauss Kruger System. Previously I am able to convert UCS to Lat Long via [Unity GPS Conversion project](https://github.com/MichaelTaylor3D/UnityGPSConverter).

Comment: This looks like a question to ask an expert in maps, not an expert in games. There's nothing particularly special about Unity's coordinate system, it's just Cartesian coordinates, with an origin and scale of your choosing. [The Geographic Information Systems StackExchange has existing Q&A about converting Gauss-Krüger to other coordinate systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gauss-Kruger). I'd recommended asking there if you don't find an existing answer you can use. Remember to specify the ellipsoid and meridian your particular GK projection is using, or link to the asset source.

Comment: Thanks you are always helpful.